# is there an issue with this php unique id generator?

Tags: php, code-generation, sha1

This code is what I plan to use for the generation of Uniques codes for tickets.

```
// A prefix to avoid uniqid collisions (when invoking this function at the same time).
// Should I use mt_rand or just rand?
$prefix = str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

// uniqid with more entropy enabled.
$unique_id = uniqid("$prefix-", TRUE);

// A SHA-1 hash for the generated code, this way it looks less sequential.
$unique_id = sha1($unique_id);
```

It'll be more helpful if you can tell me problems in this code.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Afaik you don't need to make the prefix to avoid collisions. Why? Because you can have a collision in the prefix too! `uniqid()` already has such low chance of collision that you don't need to worry about it. Also, by hashing it with a hash function (which maps an infinite set to a finite set) you introduce a high chance of collisions.

Comment: Add: I might need to correct myself a bit. Multiple hosts can still produce the same `uniqid` in the same microsecond apparently. But then you can just use the hostname as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirements, does it have to be a super secret string that nobody can ever guess?

If not, assuming that you are going to store your tickets in a database as well, you can just use `$unique_id = sha1(DATABASE_KEY);`:

```
echo sha1(1) . "\n";
echo sha1(2) . "\n";
echo sha1(3) . "\n";
```

[See the example](http://codepad.org/xxucCVFy).

Now you've got a long, interesting looking string that you don't even need to store.

Comment: But still very easy to guess, if unpredictability is a requirement. Simple integer rainbow tables are trivial to generate. A simple fixed salt would help immensely

Comment: @Marc B Of course, that's why I said that it depends on the requirements.

Comment: The problem is that I require the generated codes are not guessable, because this information is use when the ticket is used. If someone can guess codes, he could assist to the event for free.

Comment: @sanrodari: then add a salt to the hashes, some random alphanumeric string PLUS the database ID number. with a proper salt, it'll be nearly impossible to figure out how you generated the hash and will be fairly secure